# Which number is bigger than others

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Which number is bigger than others?

> $31^{42}$
>
> $21^{43}$
>
> $3^{421}$
>
> $4^{315}$

Edit:show the which is first bigger which is second bigger etc.

The last one is bigger than first because:

$31^{42}<32^{42}=4^{105}<4^{315}$

Comment: @Carry on Smiling I accidently delete your edit plese apply it again.

Comment: Since common and natural logarithms are increasing functions, the numbers will be in the same order as their logarithms, that is, if you are allowed to use logarithms.

Comment: @John Wayland Bales we didn't learn logarithem yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $31^2=961 > 882=2\cdot 21^2$, we have $$31^{42}>21^{42}\cdot 2^{21}\gg 21^{43} $$
You already verified that $4^{315}>31^{42}$.
From $4^3=64<3^4=81$, we find
$$4^{315}=(4^3)^{105}<(3^4)^{105}=3^{420}<3^{421} $$
so that in summary we have the ordering
$$3^{421}> 4^{315}>31^{42}>21^{43}$$

*Remark:* For those curious about the actual sizes of these numbers, this chain of inequalities is numerically the following (and apparently things are  far from close):
$$7.4\cdot10^{200} > 4.5\cdot 10^{189}> 4.3\cdot 10^{62} > 7.2\cdot 10^{56} $$